Wix installer throwing error while trying to run bat file
I am making exe using Bootstrapper WIX installer for my application. I am trying to get backup of the current SQL Server 2014 and restore to SQL Server 2022 after installation. Here is how my chain element looks like in the Bundle.wxs file.
    <Chain>
      <ExePackage  SourceFile="..\prerequisites\BackupDatabase2014.bat" DisplayName="Backing up 2014 Database.."  Compressed ="yes" Vital ="no" Permanent ="yes" />
      <ExePackage  SourceFile="..\prerequisites\RemoveDatabase2014.bat" DisplayName="Uninstalling 2014 database.."  Compressed ="yes" Vital ="no" Permanent ="yes" />
      <ExePackage  SourceFile="..\prerequisites\RemoveFiles.bat" DisplayName="Removing Existing Database Keys.."  Compressed ="yes" Vital ="no" Permanent ="yes" />
      <PackageGroupRef Id="Sql2022Express"/>
      <ExePackage  SourceFile="..\prerequisites\RestoreDatabase2014.bat" DisplayName="Restoring 2014 Database records.."  Compressed ="yes" Vital ="no" Permanent ="yes" />
    </Chain>

The issue I am getting is with the Backup2014Database.bat file, when I run this individually it successfully takes the backup without any error. But while running the exe file generated using the WIX Installer I get this error.
Applying execute package: BackupDatabase2014.bat, action: Install, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\812A85A2036657975578443EC126F48F631CEC9E\BackupDatabase2014.bat, arguments: '"C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\812A85A2036657975578443EC126F48F631CEC9E\BackupDatabase2014.bat"'
 Error 0x80070001: Process returned error: 0x1
 Error 0x80070001: Failed to execute EXE package.
 Error 0x80070001: Failed to configure per-machine EXE package.

Here is the BackupDatabase2014.bat file
@echo off
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions

rem Check if the script is running with administrative privileges
net session >nul 2>&1
if %errorLevel% neq 0 (
    echo This script requires administrative privileges. Please run it as an administrator.
    exit /b 1
)

echo Checking for SQL Server instance XYZInstance...
reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\Instance Names\SQL" /v XYZINSTANCE | findstr /i "MSSQL12.XYZINSTANCE" > nul 2>&1
if %errorlevel% neq 0 (
    echo XYZInstance instance not found in the registry. Exiting...
    exit /b 1
)

echo Setting backup folder path...
set "BackupFolderPath=C:\Database2014Backup"
echo Checking if the backup folder exists...
if not exist "%BackupFolderPath%" (
    echo Creating backup folder...
    mkdir "%BackupFolderPath%"
    if %errorlevel% neq 0 (
        echo Failed to create the backup folder. Exiting...
        exit /b 1
    )
)

echo Granting permissions...
icacls "%BackupFolderPath%" /grant "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM":(OI)(CI)F
if %errorlevel% neq 0 (
    echo Failed to grant permissions to the backup folder. Exiting...
    exit /b 1
)

echo Setting variables for backup...
set "ServerName=%COMPUTERNAME%\XYZInstance"
set "DatabaseName=XYZInstance"
set "BackupFileName=%DatabaseName%_Backup_%date:~4,2%-%date:~7,2%-%date:~10,4%.bak"
set "BackupFilePath=%BackupFolderPath%\%BackupFileName%"

echo Checking if the database exists...
sqlcmd -S %ServerName% -Q "IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.databases WHERE name = '%DatabaseName%') SELECT 1 ELSE SELECT 0;" -h-1 -s" " -W > nul
if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 (
    echo Performing database backup...
    sqlcmd -S %ServerName% -Q "BACKUP DATABASE [%DatabaseName%] TO DISK='%BackupFilePath%'"
    if %errorlevel% neq 0 (
        echo Database backup failed. Exiting...
        exit /b 1
    )

    echo Checking if the backup was successful...
    if exist "%BackupFilePath%" (
        echo Database backup completed successfully.
    ) else (
        echo Database backup failed. Backup file does not exist.
        exit /b 1
    )
) else (
    echo Database %DatabaseName% does not exist. Skipping backup.
)

exit /b 0


The Sequence I am trying to achieve here is :

Take Backup
Remove the current instance of SQL Server 2014
Remove the related registry keys
Install the SQL Server 2022 instance.
Restore the 2014 backup to the 2022 instance

I have tried changing the BackupDatabase2014.bat file code to make sure there is no permission issue, also the exe is executed with the administrator privileges. There are more bat files in the code which runs without any issue. I looked into multiple answers on stack overflow and other internet platforms none of them matches the case here.
I am stuck here please help, also I know using the bat file is not the best practice here, but it has been mandatory because of how the previous code of the installation was written.

Have you figured out exactly where in your .bat file it fails?

I suppose it depends on how Wix actually executes the package at runtime. If it's running headless and not loading a user profile to execute your .bat files then it's likely unable to access the Registry to query the instance names.

Change your third and fifth if %errorlevel% neq 0 instances to if errorlevel 1.

Better replace all if %errorLevel% neq 0 by if errorlevel 1. Run in a command prompt window if /? and read the output usage help. While first, second and fourth if %errorLevel% neq 0 work, it does not work within a command block beginning with ( and ending with matching ) because of every %errorlevel% with a command block is replaced already by the current value of the dynamic variable ERRORLEVEL before the if condition is evaluated at all. That can be seen on debugging the batch file.

If you would replace the second exit /b 1 by exit /b 2, the third exit /b 1 by exit /b 3 and so on, you could easily find out which condition fails on execution of the batch file on running the installer. BTW: The file extension .bat should not be used anymore for Windows batch files interpreted by the Windows Command Processor cmd.exe. There should be used now .cmd as file extension for Windows batch files. The file extension .bat is for compatibility with batch files written for interpretation by COMMAND.COM of MS-DOS, Windows 95/98/ME.

if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 can be replaced by if not errorlevel 1 which means the same because of if ERRORLEVEL is not greater or equal 1 is the same as if ERRORLEVEL less than 1 which is the same as if ERRORLEVEL equal 0. sqlcmd.exe does not exit ever with a negative value. Please specify this executable in the batch file also with file extension as written here and not with just sqlcmd. net should be replaced by %SystemRoot%\System32\net.exe and icacls by %SystemRoot%\System32\icacls.exe. That makes the batch file more fail safe and faster.

Batch files are not executables. You are instructing Burn to launch a text file as an executable and it is failing telling you that a text file is not an executable file.
Batch files are interpreted by cmd.exe. However, Burn doesn't support running cmd.exe as an executable file because, as you noted, batch files are not good practice.
You'll need to approach the problem differently.

Sounds like an interesting design problem that would require drilling into your requirements to understand the problem to make recommendations. That's beyond the scope of my answers on StackOverflow but I can be available at https://www.firegiant.com/services/
